# StringTokenizer / Split: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. Why?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand why this code gets an ArrayIndexOoB error and what I can do to fix it.

My input `Text` is formatted like `Value1:Value2`

And I want to use a `StringTokenizer` to loop through this `Text` and assign variables to each of the splits `So, String var1 = Value1`

I keep getting `IndexOutOfBounds` and I don't understand why.

```
Text value = retrieveText(this);
String word = value.toString();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(word);
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String currentWord = tokenizer.nextToken();
    String[] pieces = currentWord.split(":");
    String valOne = pieces[0];
    String valTwo = pieces[1];
    myMap.add(valOne, valTwo);
}
```

This looks correct to me so I am wondering if something is getting borked from my `Text` variable or am I missing something with `StringTokenizer` and `split(string)`

Comment: That's an older class, but simply put you're attempting to solve the same problem twice. Either use String#split or StringTokenizer (and pass your delimiter to the constructor). As it is now the delimiter you're using for the Tokenizer is something like `\r\t\h` etc, been forever since I actually looked that up

Comment: Possibly your token does not have `:`.

Comment: Does your `IndexOutOfBounds` exception tell you the line number where the error takes place (in its stack-trace). I'm guessing that `pieces` doesn't always have two elements.

Comment: And now it is a very good time to check what debugger us and how it is used.